# How do sites like this one and facebook keep track of posts

Tags: php, asp.net, web

Now i understand that a significant amount of db is used to keep track of post ids but every question has a subdirectory specified for it.  so there is a folder with the id and then the title of the question.  Is this created dynamically when a post is made? and what is stored in these dir? it seems like it would be a waste to copy the html code for each post into it and then have a specific file for each question.  Which makes me think the content is updated dynamically but then how does the html part of the code get there? is there some sort of template used that is "echoed" in a sense?  Obviously im very lost.  Ive read some stuff on MVC and i understand the concept but im am curious to know the actual mechanics that go on and what exactly is stored in these subdirectories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all dynamic.  The post content, post id and related tables are stored in the db.  The "sub-directories" you see in the URL aren't actual sub-directories that house anything, they are simply URI maps in most cases.  Download a copy of phpBB or any ecommerce platform and go through the coding, they work roughly the same way (obviously each has its own scheme as do stackoverflow and Facebook).

Comment: How is it that the uri are mapped but it still directs it to correct files?  If the dir doesnt exist how does the server know what to do

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine